# $p$-adic order of Pochhammer k-symbol

Tags: p-adic-numbers

I am with the following problem.

There is a closed formula or some lower bound for the $p$-adic valuation of the product $\prod_{k=1}^m(a+k\ell)$ (Pochhammer symbol)? where $a$ and $\ell$ are positive integers.

Comment: please don't crosspost, to avoid duplication of efforts --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152795/p-adic-order-of-pochhammer-k-symbol

Answer (score 1):

See Chapter 5, "*The $p$-adic evaluation of Pochhammer symbols*", in  [On Dwork’s $p$-adic formal congruences theorem and hypergeometric mirror maps](http://www.ams.org/books/memo/1163/) by E. Delaygue, T. Rivoal and J. Roques, Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society **246**, 1163 (2017). [A preprint from 2013 has open access [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00864745/document), see page 22.

Comment: DO you have this book? I don't have access to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't access. It ask username and password.

Comment: I found, but it is only for $\ell=1$